# How can we prevent the steaming of tiffin when we put chapatis in?

Tags: food-safety, bread, storage-method

When we put hot chapatis in the tiffin (lunch box), the lunch box get steamed. The water from steam makes the chapatis soft and sticky. How can we prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything hot in a closed environment **will** cause steam. Either cool it down first, or you can wrap them in a paper towel or kitchen paper that will absorb the moisture before putting in the container.

Answer (score -1):

you can cool it down first because hot chapaties cause steam and then wrap in aluminium foil because foil makes your chapaties hot for long time.

Comment: This seems a bit contradicting - first you recommend to cool the food, *then* to wrap it in foil to keep it hot. Could you please explain?